# Complex Limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\left [ i^i\left ( 2i \right )^{2i} \cdots\left ( ni \right )^{ni}\right ]$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Evaluate the limit:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\left [ i^i\left ( 2i \right )^{2i} \cdots\left ( ni \right )^{ni}\right ]$$

where we take into account the branch of the log. function that the argument lies within the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$.

*Any suggestions on how to begin?*

Comment: Have you tried rewriting all the powers in terms of the exponential function and the logarithm?

Comment: That is exactly what I have not done!! And I am feeling embarassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$(ki)^{ki} = e^{ki\log(ki)} = e^{ki(\log k + i\pi/2)} = e^{-k\pi/2}e^{(k\log k)i}\quad (k = 1,2,\ldots, n)$$ we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} i^{i}(2i)^{2i}\ldots (ni)^{ni} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{k = 1}^n e^{-k\pi/2} e^{(k\log k)i} = \lim_{n\to \infty} e^{-n(n+1)\pi} e^{i\sum_{k = 1}^n k\log k}.$$

Use the fact that $e^{-n(n+1)\pi} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and $|e^{i\sum_{k = 1}^n k\log k}| = 1$ to conclude that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} i^i(2i)^{2i}\cdots (ni)^{ni} = 0$.

Comment: This is slightly more than a suggestion on how to begin... :-)